# HTML Canvas - Unable to get property 'getElementById' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('ctx').getContext('2d');
</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="ctx" style="border: 1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
</body>
```

This returns:

```
0: Unable to get property 'getElementById' of undefined or null reference
```

Any reason why?

Comment: In what environment (client/browser, version?) are you running this? Everything seems fine throwing this into a stack snippet or jsfiddle/codepen...

Comment: Did you try placeing the canvas element inside body?

Comment: I've updated the code in the post. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

Add a minimum HTML document to hold the canvas.

The error is saying it can’t get getElementById from undefined, meaning document is undefined.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="ctx" style="border: 1px solid #000000";></canvas>
    <script>var ctx = document.getElementById('ctx').getContext('2d');</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Above works without error on Safari and Firefox

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code seems to be that the javascript is trying to get an element by id that does not exists the time javascript runs. So all you have to do is to place your javascript into the end of the document (for some simple tests). When coding something "real" application you should wrap your javascript in some kind of on-load handler to be sure it is only fired after the document is loaded completely.

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="ctx" width="150" height="150"></canvas>

<script>
  var ctx = document.getElementById('ctx').getContext('2d');
  console.log(ctx)
</script>

</body>
</html>
```